# $\operatorname{Res}(f,-i)$ for $f(z) = \frac{1}{z} + \exp\left(\frac{z-i}{z^2+1} \right)$ at $z = -i$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

How do I show that $z = -i$ is an essential singularity of $f(z) = \frac{1}{z} + \exp\left(\frac{z-i}{z^2+1} \right)$  and find its Residue $\operatorname{Res}(f,-i)$?

My idea was to show that the principle part of the Laurent series around $z = -i$ of $f$ has infinitely many terms but somehow I don't know how to deal with the $\frac{1}{z}$.

And of course I do know that 
\begin{align}
\exp\left(\frac{z-i}{z^2+1} \right) = \exp\left(\frac{1}{z+i} \right) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k! (z+i)^k}.
\end{align}

Would anyone be so kind to help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It follows from your computations that the residue at $-i$ of $\exp\left(\frac{z-i}{z^2+1}\right)=1$. Since the residue at $-i$ of $\frac1z$ is $0$, $\operatorname{Res}(f,-i)=1$.

Comment: Maybe I should refine my question. What is the Laurent series of $f$ around $z = -i$? Is it simply $f(z) = \frac{1}{z} + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!(z+i)^k}$ or do I need to somehow deal with the $\frac{1}{z}$?

Comment: No. It's$$i+(z+i)-i (z+i)^2-(z+i)^3+i (z+i)^4+(z+i)^5+\cdots$$It's just the Taylor series of $\frac1z$ centered at $-i$.

Comment: So the Laurent series is $ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} i(-i)^k(i+z)^k + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!(z+i)^k}$ and therefore $-i$ has to be an essential singularity and the Residue is $1$. Correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.